# Filtering records that occur more than once with multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a sample dataset. My objective is to keep any records whose `user_id` **and** `plan_id` occur more than once.  I understand that you can count the frequency of a variable in a column with

```
n_occur <- data.frame(table(test$user_id))
```

But how would one count the frequency of variables in two columns *and then* filter the original dataset by those that occur more than once? 
For example, here is my test dataset:

```
> test
   user_id plan_id hour
1        1      10    2
2        2      10    4
3        3      20   23
4        4      20   12
5        5      10    8
6        1      10   10
7        5      20    6
8        1      20    5
9        1      20   18
10       5      10    7
11       1      30    6
```

And here is the intended output:

```
> output
  user_id plan_id hour
1       1      10    2
2       5      10    8
3       1      10   10
4       1      20    5
5       1      20    8
6       5      10   17
```

and the data:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(user_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1), 
    plan_id = c(10, 10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 10, 30), 
    hour = c(2, 4, 23, 12, 8, 10, 6, 5, 18, 7, 6)), .Names = c("user_id", 
"plan_id", "hour"), row.names = c(NA, 11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: this is not a duplicate because it offers a base R solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` to check the `id` columns from the beginning and from the end, if either returns TRUE, the row appears more than once; Then you can use the returned logical vector to subset the data frame:

```
ids <- df[c('user_id', 'plan_id')]
df[duplicated(ids) | duplicated(ids, fromLast = TRUE),]

#   user_id plan_id hour
#1        1      10    2
#5        5      10    8
#6        1      10   10
#8        1      20    5
#9        1      20   18
#10       5      10    7
```